# Vue Button "Add one item to cart" component design using axios and laravel backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have designed a Vue3 shopping cart. The shopping cart has an "Add One" button. When this button is pressed it will update an *input type= "number"* and it will update the database using Axios (the backend is  Laravel and uses a createOrUpdate method). I am also sending this Axios request whenever the input field changes. In other words, the user has the option to manually type the amount in the field or they can press the plus button which will update the input field +1 and will update the database using Axios in both scenarios.

Current Code;

```
<input
                name="qtyInput"
                type="number"
                v-model="qtyInput"
            />

<button @click="addOneItem" >ADD ONE TO CART</button>
```

I have a watcher, using a watch function whenever it detects a change in the qty const it triggers the addProductToCart() function which sends the Axios request.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
setup() {
const qty = ref(0);
const qtyInput = ref(0);
let cartitem = ref({
            product_id: 1,
            qty: qty,
        });

const addOneItem = () => {
                qty.value++;
qty.value = qtyInput.value;
           
        };

const addProductToCart = () => {
                axios
                    .post("/api/update-cart/", cartitem.value)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log('works well, saved in db!');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        return error;
                    });
            } 
        };


watch(qty, async (newQty, oldQty) => {
                addProductToCart();
        });



return {
            qtyInput,
qty,
            addOneItem,
cartitem
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Note: My original code is much more complex than this and everything works fine. For the purpose of this example I have shaved down the amount of code, I hope that everything makes sense.

My question is: Whenever the user clicks the "Add One" button really fast, let's say around 20 times, I get an Axios error "Too Many Requests". I also find it very inefficient that for every click there is an Axios request to createOrUpdate in the Laravel backend. **How can I improve this system design to prevent so many requests but at the same time allow the user to click as many times as he wants without erroring out?
**

Comment: Does the cart _need_ to be saved to a database after every change?  It's an atypical use case for a database. Usually the order/cart information would be saved to the db once the order is finalized and submitted.  While still in progress a cart's info can usually be handled solely by the frontend.  However, if your situation necessitates these database changes you can use a technique called [debouncing](https://vueuse.org/shared/useDebounceFn/#usedebouncefn) to only call your function once the user has stopped rapidly clicking.

Comment: It does not need to be saved into a db. What other approaches are there? It is important that if the user leaves and returns later his cart is untouched.

Comment: Browsers have memory you can save information to that can persist between page loads.  Research "localStorage" and "sessionStorage", e.g. [this article](https://javascript.info/localstorage).  There is no special library you need to use it, it's built into the JS web API. It's also debuggable with browser dev tools. In chrome the "Application" tab shows saved localStorage key-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question i suggest you to use `useDebounceFn` or `watchThrottled` from vueuse. More information can be found [here](https://vueuse.org/shared/useDebounceFn/).

Another option would be that you save the the cart in the localStorage. Therefore you can use [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) and [pinia-plugin-persistedstate](https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate).